# Acessando um Widget PyQt5 e módulos dentro de um package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt-5, qtgui

Estou fazendo um programa utilizando como GUI o framework `PyQt5`, usando arquivos UI. Estou tendo problemas para acessar o módulo dentro do arquivo `.py` que crio para que eu coloque as funções dentro delas e assim organizar melhor o meu programa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função que quero chamar é a `char_1` que está dentro de `characters.py`.
No programa principal `main.py` eu o importo da seguinte maneira `from util.images.characters import checar`, mas desta forma ele me retorna este erro:

**`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'util.images.characters' has no attribute 'checar' (most likely due to a circular import)`**

De alguma forma, ele só consegue acessar a função quando ela está dentro do arquivo `__init__.py` da pasta `images`.
Queria saber, a fim de organizar o meu programa, como consigo acessar esta função dentro do arquivo `characters.py`.
Abaixo se segue os códigos "resumidos" do programa.
OBS: `actionAlbedo` é o nome do item do `QAction` do `QMenu` do arquivo `ui/tela.ui`.

> **`main.py`**

```py
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtGui
from util.images.characters import checar

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

tela = uic.loadUi('ui/tela.ui')
tela.actionAlbedo.triggered.connect(checar)

tela.show()
app.exec_()
```

> **`characters.py`**

```py
import main
from PyQt5 import QtGui


def checar():
    main.tela.lb_background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('img/background/char_1.png'))
```

Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está o erro:

`(most likely due to a circular import)`

Quando você importa um arquivo, o código que está dentro dele é executado. Logo, o arquivo **main.py** está executando o arquivo **characters.py** que novamente chama o arquivo **main.py**. Levantando, assim, uma importação circular.

Uma solução pra isso seria passar a variável **tela** que você quer acessar no arquivo *characters.py* como um parâmetro da função.

```
def checar(tela):
    tela.lb_background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('img/background/char_1.png'))
```

Comment: Alan, deste jeito não deu certo. Tentei de outro jeito. Eliminei diretório `images` e criei outro diretório python chamado `characters`. Nele, coloquei no arquivo `__init__.py` o código.
Então no `main.py` coloquei `from util import characters`. No comando coloquei `tela.actionAlbedo.triggered.connect(characters.checar)`. Mas ainda assim dá este erro: `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'util.characters' has no attribute 'mudar' (most likely due to a circular import)`.
Caso queira ver o original está em https://github.com/LucasRibeiroRJBR/genshin_app na pasta `pyqt5`. Obrigado.